# Apache Spark running slower when IntelliJ not in focus

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I am running Apache Spark in IntelliJ, using the console to send requests to my application.
I have noticed something I find quite strange. On my Mac, when running my program and having IntelliJ as the selected window i.e. full screen and visible; I get through 1000 iterations in ~5 minutes. When I start the application in IntelliJ and then make the visible screen another application, but do nothing with it - literally just leave the Mac alone, when I go back to the Scala Console after ~5 minutes it has only performed 300 iterations! Similarly, if the app starts and then the screens turns off (but my Mac doesn't sleep - I made sure of that) I get the same issue: only 300 iterations.

Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: I hoped there will be more activity here. Can you reproduce this with some other application, maybe not with spark, simpler?

Comment: Good idea! I will transfer some Java projects across into IntelliJ and see the outcome!